# Microsoft Shadow Filter - No Direction?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, filter

Is it possible to use this filter to create a directionless drop shadow (The shadow appears on all sides of a div?)

`filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#969696', Direction=145, Strength=3);`

It would create something similar to:

`box-shadow: 0 0 4px #969696;`

Comment: How about http://css3pie.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not a cross-browser semantic way to approach creating box-shadow functionality in IE. The .Shadow() filter you have is the closest you're going to get.

Also, [this page](http://placenamehere.com/article/384/css3boxshadowininternetexplorerblurshadow/) should prove to be an informative read.

Comment: Thanks, just wanted someone to confirm what I wanted to do couldn't be done with the shadow function. The blur function isn't really appropriate in my scenario. I will just add a 1px faint pixel on the sides without a border and IE can have directional shadows on everything

Comment: Personally, I'd just ignore it altogether in IE. Have the `box-shadow` defined for browsers that can read it, and don't worry about the browser that can't.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible, just use multiple .shadow declarations each with a different direction.

This will give you something close to what you are looking for - the various strengths are used to blend the edges a little better.

```
filter: 
  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#969696,direction=0,strength=5), 
  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#969696,direction=45,strength=2), 
  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#969696,direction=90,strength=5), 
  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#969696,direction=135,strength=5), 
  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#969696,direction=180,strength=10), 
  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#969696,direction=225,strength=5), 
  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#969696,direction=270,strength=5), 
  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#969696,direction=315,strength=2);
```

A demo can be viewed here: http://hedgerwow.appspot.com/demo/shadow

And for more information on IE filters see this MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847(v=vs.85).aspx